# redmine chat plugin how to install

Tags: ruby, plugins, redmine

In redmine bitnami, I try to install redmine chat.
The plugin is below.

http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_chat

I did it following explanation of this page, but I could't it.
The ruby's error message is appered.
My environment is

・windows 10
・only install bitnami redmine

If somebody knows how to install redmine chat, please tell me.
I want to know procedure of install.

Below is the explanation of the install.
If you can install this, please tell me command line and procedure.

p.s I use the zip file and put the directory of  "plugins" folder.

---

First briefly talk to you, it's not recommended to install it unless the future version of 0.1.0
1.the installation process
Git from bitbucket in the plugins direction: git clone https://39648421@bitbucket.org/39648421/redmine_chat.git
Or download it from bitbucket and expand zip file into the plugins directory and name it by redmine_chat
In redmine home directory, run: bundle install --without development test.
Please run bundle update private_pub if you have bundled from tigergm's github
In redmine home directory, run: RAILS_ENV=production rails g private_pub:install. It will generate a few template files
Edit private_pub.ru file in redmine home directory, such as changes to the mysql sqlite3
Edit private_pub.yml file in config directory, such as the server production according to the the server's ip or domain name
In redmine main directory, start faye server, distribute and monitor chat messages, it may be necessary preceded bundle exec. You can add "-D" in the end as backgound daemon. Run: 
rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
Other example if you want to listen all:
rackup -o 0.0.0.0 private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
Migrate database files in redmine home directory, run:
bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_chat RAILS_ENV=production
Restart redmine and use the plugin.

---

I tryied to changing plugin's gemfile and did bundle install --no-deployment.
After doing that, run rake command.
Install was success,but error message was appered in production.log.
help me.

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial layouts/_chat_head with {:locale=>[:ja, :en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :rsb]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.3.1-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/views"
):
    13: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'rtl', :media => 'all' if l(:direction) == 'rtl' %>
    14: <%= javascript_heads %>
    15: <%= heads_for_theme %>
    16: <%= call_hook :view_layouts_base_html_head %>
    17: 
    18: <%= yield :header_tags -%>
    19: 
  lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in render_on'
  lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:57:in`map'
  lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:57:in `block in render_on'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in`block (2 levels) in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `each'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in`block in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `tap'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in`call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:96:in `call_hook'
  app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:16:in`_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb__911853101_45405108'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:488:in `block (2 levels) in render_error'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:486:in`render_error'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:474:in `render_404'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:498:in`missing_template'

Answer (score 0):

Copy the plugin to `c:/redmine/plugins folder`

Go to run command line `cd c:/redmine/plugins folder`

run the command

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Ref http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/37506

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I failed the install when I entered "rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production".  Did you success it??

Comment: error massage is "You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: thin (= 1.6.1) and thin (>= 0)"

Comment: there are two Gemfiles in directory of redmine/htdocs  and plugin.I think it needs changing or delete something.

Comment: plugins gemfiles writing "gem 'private_pub', :github => 'tigergm/rm_private_pub'
gem 'thin'"

Comment: I deleted "thin" from plugins gemfile, then another erorr message appered. 「The git source git://github.com/tigergm/rm_private_pub.git is not yet checked ou
t. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application

Comment: run bundle install --no-deployment, and run rake command ,then install was success.but internal error is occured..... Error message is writing above, if u can find please tell me.